# Understanding Javascript Documentation

Tags: javascript

I know this is a silly question so please go easy. 
I'm having trouble understanding documentation in general such as this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Can someone explain the terms 'callback' 'currentValue' 'index' 'array' (in that context) and 'thisArg' in very basic layman's? I'm sure it's something simple but it's just not clicking in my brain, and it's making learning the language on my own very difficult so I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think it's a silly question, nor do I agree with the votes to close.  It is broad, but not overly broad that a simple (technical) answer can't cover it.

Comment: `callback` and `thisArg` are simply *labels* that refer to the arguments that are supposed to be passed to `.map`. The documentation could also say "The first argument....". Similarly `currentValue`, `index` and `array` are labels for the arguments that are passed to the first argument (`callback`).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answers, I'm extremely grateful and really didn't expect any response at all! I knew it would be something obvious but I just couldn't work it out for some reason. Thanks to everyone's answers and then having a play in a js console I now seem to have got my head round it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to make it very simple and understandable.

A **callback** function is passed as an argument to a function (like `age` is passed to `foo` in the example below) and is executed after a certain event. It is called *callback* because it is executed not before the *parent* function (to which the *callback* function was passed to as an argument) itself is executed.

For example:

```
function foo(age, function callBack()) {
    print("I am " + age + " years old");
}

function gender() {
    print(" and male");
}

function certainEvent() {
 foo(99, gender);
}
```

If you now call certainEvent(), the result would be:

```
I am 99 years old and male
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and easy to understand explanation, I am finally getting my head round it. :)

Comment: This isn't  syntactically valid javascript

Comment: I am aware of that. There is no need to use javascript syntax to explain the principles of callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

`callback` is a function that you pass to map. It will be called with the arguments `currentValue`, `index` and `array`.

For instance using a callback that logs:

```
   [1, 2, 3].map(function(currentValue, index, array) {
        console.log("currentValue", currentValue);
        console.log("index", index);
        console.log("array", array);
   });
```

Logs:

```
currentValue 1
index 0
array [1, 2, 3]
currentValue 2
index 1
array [1, 2, 3]
currentValue 3
index 2
array [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that the function doesn't have to inline, this is equal:

```
   function mapper(currentValue, index, array) {
        console.log("currentValue", currentValue);
        console.log("index", index);
        console.log("array", array);
   }

   [1, 2, 3].map(mapper);
```

Comment: ... and `thisArg`, if supplied (which is fairly unusual) supplies the arguments which will be `this` when the callback function is executed.

Comment: @Esailija @Scott Sauyet Thank you for the explanation. I've had a play around in the console and am I right in thinking when you do something like the below example the `num` argument is the `currentValue` part? If yes I was wondering what you can do with the `index` and `array` arguments? As in what sort of situation would you use those?
`var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var doubles = numbers.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});`

Comment: I've spent a lot of time working on a [functional programming library](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) which doesn't supply these by default; I in fact think it's often better not to have them.  :-).  That said, they can be useful, especially the `index`: `var stretches = arr.map(function(el, idx, list) {return idx == 0 ? "start" : el >= list[idx - 1] ? "increasing" : "decreasing";})`.  Applied to `[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6]`, this yields  `["start", "decreasing", "increasing", "decreasing", "increasing", "increasing", "decreasing", "increasing"]`.  But they're often not needed.

Answer (score 2):

`.map` is a function. Function usually accept **arguments**. The part you are referring to describes the arguments and their purpose in more detail. Lets have a look at the **signature** of the function:

```
arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

This tells you that the function takes two arguments, where the second argument is optional (indicated by the `[...]`).

The documentation chose to *name* the first argument "callback" and the second argument "thisArg". It could have chosen different names ore no names at all and simply referred to the "first" and "second" argument.

Of course the chosen names carry some meaning, but this is only secondary. Naming them at all is done to be able to easily refer to those arguments later in the documentation. Whenever you see `callback` (i.e. formatted as code) in the documentation for `.map`, such as

> Value to use as `this` when executing `callback`.

you know that it refers to the *first* argument.

Similarly "currentValue", "index" and "array" are labels for the arguments that are passed to the first argument of `.map` ("callback"), since that argument is supposed to be a function as well.

`currentValue` by itself doesn't really mean anything. However, in the context of `.map` it refers to the first argument that is passes to the first argument of `.map`. It's meaning is described in the documentation:

> The current element being processed in the array.

---

This follows the typical way we write functions. When you declare a function, you usually give the parameters names. For example:

```
function first(arr) {
    return arr[0];
}
```

Here I am giving the first parameter the name `arr` so I can refer to it more easily later. The same happens in the documentation: The parameter/argument gets a name so it can easily be referred to later.

Answer (score 1):

The map method has two arguments. The callback and the scoping parameter.

The *callback* is the function that you set that does the processing. It has three arguments that give you the state of the current iteration as map loops over the array.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function callback ( currentValue, index, array) {
   console.group("callback called");
   console.log("currentValue:", currentValue);  //Current value of the index aka `array[index]`
   console.log("index:", index);  //current index of the loop (think of it as a for loop (var i=0; i<array.lenght; i++) It would be i.
   console.log("array:", array);  //The array you are looping over..aka a reference to myArray 
   console.groupEnd("callback called");
   return currentValue * 2;
}

var result = myArray.map(callback);
console.log(result);
```

And the [] in the method declaration `[, thisArg]` states that that parameter/argument is optional.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, if the `currentValue` is like a for loop, can I put in a number as the second argument to start the iteration at a different point in the array? (hope that makes sense!) Or are those arguments purely there so you can see the actual `index` and `array` being executed?